# add new data to the old in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have this script:

```
foreach ($_GET[selected] as &$value) {
    echo "$value|";
    mysql_query("UPDATE ordre SET enheder='$row3[enheder]|$value' WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

It doesn't do what I want to. I want it to add the strings from array $value to rest thats already in MySql.

If

```
$value = "Server1|Server2|Server3|";
```

Then it should update "enheder" to "OLD TEXT|Server1|Server2|Server3|" but it doesn't?

Comment: *"I want it to add the strings"* - If you want to add, then don't use `UPDATE` use [`INSERT`](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-insert-statement.htm) yet I don't quite get this `enheder='$row3[enheder]|$value'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I read the question as meaning that the OP wants to update the value with id='1' with new text appended to the old text.

Comment: @Gus To tell you the truth, I had a hard time understanding. Looks like you figured it out ;-)

Comment: $_GET[selected] is incorrect, prefer $_GET['selected'].
You should always check the input variables, this one allows user to do an SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to build the string you want to add in php, then use MySQL's `CONCAT()` function to add this one string to the value already in the database. Also, as you are creating your sql from user input, escaping this input is also essential.

One way you could do the above is:

```
<?php
    $values = mysql_real_escape_string(implode("|", $_GET['selected'])) ;
    $sql = "
UPDATE ordre
SET enheder = CONCAT(enheder, '|', '{$values}')
WHERE id = '1'
    " ;
    mysql_query($sql) ;
?>
```

Comment: $_GET['selected'] dosnt have all the infomations.

the url looks like this: ?selected%5B%5D=Server1&selected%5B%5D=Server2&selected%5B%5D=Server3&selected%5B%5D=Server4

All %5B and D is []

So when im using yours code it only updates it with ||||

Comment: @CasperMartinsen That url would be processed by php as array stored in $_GET['selected'], with each value ('Server1', 'Server2' etc.) being an element in that array. Try running `var_dump($_GET['selected']);` to see what you get.

Comment: Thanks Gus that work. It was my mistake it didnt worked first time ;)